# Replace the entire string if there is a partial match in Polars

Tags: r, python-polars

I am trying to translate R's dplyr code to R Polars, which replaces entire string with another if there is a partial match.

```
library(polars)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(category = c('Cats A','Cats B','kittens','street cats','dogs A','dogs B'))

#replace string that contains 'cats' and 'kitten' with 'cats'
df %>% 
  mutate(replaced = replace(category,
                            grepl(paste0(c('cats','kittens'), collapse = '|'), category, ignore.case = TRUE),
                            'CATS')
         )

#Output
     category replaced
      Cats A     CATS
      Cats B     CATS
     kittens     CATS
 street cats     CATS
      dogs A   dogs A
      dogs B   dogs B
```

I want to replicate this in Polars and attempted something like:

```
p_df <- pl$DataFrame(df) #to polars dataframe
p_df$with_columns(replaced = pl$col('category')$str$replace_many(c("Cats","kittens"),"CATS"))
```

and
`...$str$replace(r"{cats}",'Cats'))` This replaces only the matched part, not the entire string. Not sure how to make it work. A Python implementation will also help.

```
#output
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ category    ┆ replaced    │
│ ---         ┆ ---         │
│ str         ┆ str         │
╞═════════════╪═════════════╡
│ Cats A      ┆ CATS A      │
│ Cats B      ┆ CATS B      │
│ kittens     ┆ CATS        │
│ street cats ┆ street cats │
│ dogs A      ┆ dogs A      │
│ dogs B      ┆ dogs B      │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know R but it looks like the first example builds a regex delimited by `|`?

You can do it at the "regex level" in a similar way:

- wrap the `|` delimited partials in `(?:)`
- `(?i)` to ignore case
- use the `.*` "wildcard" on either side of the partials to match "anything"

```py
df.with_columns(replaced =
   pl.col("category").str.replace(r"(?i).*(?:cats|kittens).*", "CATS")
)
```

```py
shape: (6, 2)
┌─────────────┬──────────┐
│ category    ┆ replaced │
│ ---         ┆ ---      │
│ str         ┆ str      │
╞═════════════╪══════════╡
│ Cats A      ┆ CATS     │
│ Cats B      ┆ CATS     │
│ kittens     ┆ CATS     │
│ street cats ┆ CATS     │
│ dogs A      ┆ dogs A   │
│ dogs B      ┆ dogs B   │
└─────────────┴──────────┘
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. R implemenetation would be `...$str$replace(r"{(?i).*(?:cats|kittens).*}", "CATS"))`, with the
addition of "{}" to treat it as raw string literal.
grepl() function in R is used for pattern matching. The paste0(... '|') part creates a regex, in which '|' is an 'or' operator and acts as a separator. It checks if either 'cats' or 'kittens' present in a string.